# Method position error

Tags: javascript, percentage

I want to calculate 17% from 835 and after reduce from n the resulted number.
But the resulted number is 693.5 and I want to show downwards to the nearest integer 693.
The Math.floor should do that but I don't understand why the resulted number shown is 694.
Thank you.

```
function compute_active_users(n, b) {
// Write your code here
var s =b/100*n;
var b =Math.floor(s);

console.log(n-b);

}
compute_active_users(835,17);
```

Comment: Google + Good attitude = Answers

Comment: I am sorry for the Title, I know it's rude but I am in a hurry and It wont let me to say in title what I want so I reduce It to this.

Comment: Again I am very sorry about that. I didn't want to be rude!

Comment: you are taking the `floor` too early.

Comment: I tryed to put the result of n - b in a variable sum. and after I call the console.log(Math.floor(sum)); and it didn't work either

Comment: @AndreiR.Beraru `b` is the problem. `floor` after subtracting, not before.

Comment: Use the `edit` link (below your post) to change the title of your post to something relevant. Doing so will help others see your post and reply with an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey you should do

```
function compute_active_users(n, b) {
// Write your code here
var s = b /100 *n;
var b = Math.floor(n - s);
console.log(b);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This site, and most of you helped me alot! And I respect you for that!